# Unable to send two params in URL path to python

Tags: python, url, url-pattern

I'm using pythons in backend and i like to get some data through URL, simply i can say as through REST. My URL works with single param but fails for two params. Please refer below two URL

Single param:

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff"  <URL>?attr1=testvalue
```

Two param:

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff"  <URL>?attr1=testvalue&attr2=133
```

I cross verify that, python code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may missed out escape key() after & in the URL, try this one.... i hope this will work

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff"  <URL>?attr1=testvalue\&attr2=133
```

I faced similar problem, it works. make an try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is interpreted by shell. Strings before and after `&` are treated as separated command. (BTW, `&` means *run in background* in shell).

To prevent that, quote the url:

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff" "<url>?attr1=testvalue&attr2=133"
```

or

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff" '<url>?attr1=testvalue&attr2=133'
```

or escape the `&`:

```
curl -XPUT -HContent-type:text/plain --data "stuff:morestuff" <url>?attr1=testvalue\&attr2=133
```